# Python - Search for substring in list from a list of substrings

Tags: python, list, substring

Trying to use a list of keywords to search another list of strings by the keywords. Some of them are formatted a bit weird.

```py
results_list = ['user 1 \n    date of birth', '11 Jan 1990','user 1 age', '29','user 1 income', '60 000',
'user 2 \n    username', 'guest_user2','user 2 age', '25','user 2 income', '45 000']
keywords = ['date of birth','age','income','username']
```

I tried this code:

```py
final_dict = {}
for r in range(len(results_list)):
   for word in range(len(keywords)):
       if keywords[words] in results_list[r]:
           print(keywords[word])
           print(results_list[r])
           r_key_idx = results_list.index(results_list[r])
           r_val_idx = r_key_idx + 1
           dictionary = {results_list[r_key_idx]:results_list[r_val_idx]}
           final_dict.update(dictionary)
```

This results in an output dictionary of

```py
{'user 1 age':'29', 'user1 income':'60 000', 'user 2 age':'25', 'user2 income':'45 000'}
```

*note, in this example it finds the substrings. but in my working dataset, it does not. tested it in repl.it and it worked.

It doesn't seem to grab the ones that have the `\n` in it. I don't want to just make bunch of different keywords because it changes quite often, based on the values in the table and it's quite a large table and making hundreds of different keywords with the `\n` just seems self-defeating.

Also, note the examples are not the same as my actual dataset (the actual dataset has about 12 spaces after the `\n`, not sure if that would change anything though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sanitizing your data list first and then run your code. Sanitize your data like this below. Your keywords should match after this.

```
results_list = ['user 1 \n    date of birth', '11 Jan 1990','user 1 age', '29','user 1 income', '60 000',
'user 2 \n    username', 'guest_user2','user 2 age', '25','user 2 income', '45 000']

for index, res in enumerate(results_list):
    if '\n' in res:
        new_res = res.split('\n')
        #remove empty space to the left
        new_res[1] = new_res[1].lstrip(" ")
        results_list[index] = "".join(new_res)

print(results_list)#place your code after this line


#['user 1 date of birth', '11 Jan 1990', 'user 1 age', '29', 'user 1 income', '60 000', 'user 2 username', 'guest_user2', 'user 2 age', '25', 'user 2 income', '45 000']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean your string before comparison.

One more thing if you results_list always have a key and its value on next index then you can use range method with jump parameter(3rd parameter)

```
final_dict = {}
for i in range(0, len(results_list), 2):
    # This will change multiple spaces into 1 including \n
    key = " ".join(results_list[i].split())
    print(key)
    if [keyword for keyword in keywords if keyword in key]:
        final_dict[key] = results_list[i+1]
```